# Horizontal partitioning of tables in multitenant shared environments

Tags: database, relational-database, multi-tenant, partitioning

I have a database where I need to store data (e.g. resources) coming from different users (i.e. tenants).

Those resources can be shared across several users.

Therefore I have a table of Users, a table of Resources and a many-to-many table UserResources.

```
TABLE Users (GUID userId, String username);

TABLE Resources (GUID resourceId, String resourcePath, DateTime createdAt, DateTime updatedAt, int property1, ...);

TABLE UserResources (GUID userId, GUID resourceId);
```

**What is the most efficient strategy for the horizontal partition of the table 'UserResources'?**

that is

**Which columns should I use as partitioning columns in UserResources to have the best performances (in terms of execution time) of queries?**

Thank you all!

cghersi

Comment: Hi. You are asking textbook & manual chapters on basics of multi-tenant partitioning & asking us to apply them to a very general case. Please read some & ask a specific question with appropriate details. [ask]

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Thanks philipxy for the comments. Actually I think this is a very specific question; I tried to explicitly add it at the end. Of course the try&measure  approach is optimal, I just want to have a hint on where to start from, not to lose months in trial&errors...

Comment: @CristianoGhersi - Which database engine are you using?  It can make a big difference.

Comment: GUIDs suck on performance; do you really need that kind of id?

Comment: @RickJames: I am experimenting with SQL Server (Azure DB Service and SQL Server 2016 onPrem), and Mobile App service, which unfortunately use GUIDs as PKs of the autogenerated tables... BTW, what do you suggest for PKs, if I had the chance to change?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi - If it is practical to have a single source of ids, the use `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or other type of sequence generator).  If you must generate ids independently in multiple servers, then you are stuck with GUIDs (UUIDs).  Some discussion here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/uuid

Comment: @RickJames: I see. Another point, how do you cope with unique ids if you have to merge two or more instance of databases? E.g. you have two instances of database belonging to two different customers, but then you want to merge such instances into a single one: how do you avoid clashes?

Comment: @CristianoGhersi - Have another column with the `customer_id`, and make that part of the `PRIMARY KEY`.  (There are some issues with that, too.)

Comment: @RickJames, thanks for the hint, I saw the strategy that you propose as one of the options; unfortunately this means that all the foreign keys that point to that entity should go with a double key (so the question is: is it better a double-column numeric key or a single-column GUID?)

Comment: @CristianoGhersi - Hard to give a one-size-fits-all answer.  Depends on table sizes, whether FKs are really needed (INDEXes are needed).  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

It does not make sense to partition a many-to-many table.  You are not likely to gain any performance.  In fact, performance may suffer.

My tips on many-to-many tables (for MySQL):  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table